# Google My Business API location list missing locations

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, google-my-business-api

I am making a list call to the GMB API like so:

```
locations_list = service.accounts().locations().list(parent=parent).execute()
```

The result of this are a list of the GMB locations associated to the Oauth logged in account.

The issue is that there are SOME missing locations in the api results compared to all the locations on the GMB dashboard.

I know the oauth verification and the request is working because I am getting most of the locations as a result.

Note: Some of the locations have been shared to this account (by making my account a manager), but doesn't form a pattern for the ones that are missing. The missing ones are also all verified.

Answer (score 0):

Are you only getting the first 20 locations? If so, use the `nextPageToken` from the initial response and resubmit the request until there is no more `nextPageToken`.

Comment: That doesnt seem to the issue. I am retrieving 174 locations and am not using any nextPageToken and it doesnt seem like there is an order to which ones are missing.